# c exec embeded in webpage

Tags: c, executable

Does anyone know for a tool that allows a c executable to be run in the browser?  I'm looking for a javascript, java, or flash solution because I don't have privileges to run c executables on the server.

The executables are basic input and output programs.

Comment: This kind of thing doesn't exist for obvious security reasons.

Comment: write a java wrapper to call it and display its outputs?
http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.lang/Exec.html

Comment: I know the most obvious solution is to rewrite the programs in a scripting language, but that won't work for this.  I have students that want to show off their c executables on a webpage.

Comment: I see how there are obvious security reasons if you are running an executable on someones machine, but in the browser, or a jvm?

Comment: Executable running in browser? You may provide a way to user to download the app and run it on their system. Just create link to the file in html to download it.

Comment: The java wrapper relies on System Calls, downloading the executable and running it does cause security vulnerabilities.

Comment: Even if there was a way of "running an executable" in a browser or jvm, it would still be running on the client machine, which is absolutely ridiculous considering the fact that you're going to run into some very basic problems such as processor architecture and platform dependence for the c executable. Just write some script in something like php that invokes the c program server-side and returns the output... and I don't understand how you don't have "privileges to run a c executable" unless you don't have access to the machine at all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your comments, I hear you mention students and running simple programs. As a suggestion, you might want to look into [CodePad](http://codepad.org/). This will let you interpret simple C programs. Note that everything needs to be in one place, so you'll have to combine C and header files.

Here is a sample:

http://codepad.org/qQS31BwM

***EDIT***

Here's another one I found:

http://ideone.com/

When you run the program, at the bottom there is a link for input. You can use it to run the program with given input as entered.

Comment: That's close, but it doesn't allow for user input, just output.  THANKS!

Comment: @QuinnBaetz I just added another solution like Codepad, but it allows you to enter input after first compilation at run by the controls at the bottom.

Comment: This isn't quite what I was looking for because it requires all of the input to be given at the beginning, but I think it's the closest I'm going to get.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this as a basis for solving the problem:

http://bellard.org/jslinux/

Answer (score 0):

> [Emscripten](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki) is an **LLVM**-to-**JavaScript** compiler. It takes LLVM bitcode (which can be generated from C/C++, using llvm-gcc or clang, or any other language that can be converted into LLVM) and compiles that into JavaScript, which can be run on the web (or anywhere else JavaScript can run).
>
> Using Emscripten, you can
>
> - Compile C and C++ code into JavaScript and run that on the web
> - Run code in languages like Python as well, by compiling CPython from C to JavaScript and interpreting code in that on the web